# Django: How to get and save a foreign key field in POST method

Tags: django

I am try to save a data in two models Booking and Event. The first one working well but I get error in the Event, I don't know how to get and save the foreign key data.
This is my Event model:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    place = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True)
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True,null=True)
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True,null=True)
```

And this is my views:

```
def registerBooking(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BookingForm(request.POST)
        place = request.POST.get('place','')
        visit_type = request.POST.get('visit_type','')
        description = request.POST.get('description','')
        patient = request.POST.get('patient','')
        doctor = request.POST.get('doctor','')
        created_at = request.POST.get('created_at','')
    

        if form.is_valid():
            new_booking = form.save()
            new_event = Event(title=visit_type,description=description,start_time=created_at,place=place,patient=patient,doctor=doctor)
            new_event.save()
            return JsonResponse({"msg":"Booking and Event successfully saved."})
            #return redirect(reverse('dashboard'))
        else:
            return JsonResponse({"msg":"Invalid data"})
    else:
        form = BookingForm()
    return render(request, 'patient/register_booking.html', {'form':form})
```

new_booking is working but the problem is in new_event, I get this error:
"ValueError: Cannot assign "'1'": "Event.patient" must be a "Patient" instance."

Comment: You don't say what your error is...  You need to tell us that.  But, the easiest way to solve this problem is to use a second form class EventForm.  You can put both form instances into the context and then render them as one form.

Answer (score 1):

I gues you get this error because you got pk of `Patient` in `patient` variable, and Django wait `Patient` instance when save.

You can get `Patient` instance with `patient = Patient.objects.filter(pk = request.POST.get('patient','')).first()` and then use it on creating `Event`

If there is no `Patient` with `pk` you got in `request.POST` you will get `None` in `patient`, and after creating `Event`, `patient` field in it will be `None` as well

Same for `Doctor` instance

Comment: Perfect, it works well for me. Thank you so much

Comment: Glad to hear, consider accepting the answer, if it was useful.